# Apple Aluminum Keyboard and Ubunutu 11.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-11.04

I have connected this Apple Aluminum keyboard to my Ubuntu-running PC. The thing is, `F` (*function*) keys are not working as I want them to work. There are `eject` key, and `volume` keys (keys with icons), they do eject and rise/lower volume – but I need the `F` functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three modes according to the [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard):

> - 0 – Disable the 'fn' key. Pressing 'fn'+'F8' will behave like you only
>     press 'F8'
> - 1 – Function keys are used as last key. Pressing 'F8' key will act as a
>     special key. Pressing 'fn'+'F8' will behave like a F8.
> - 2 – Function keys are used as first key. Pressing 'F8' key will behave
>     like a F8. Pressing 'fn'+'F8' will act as special key (play/pause).

It sounds like you want mode 2.

---

Change the setting **temporarily** by entering the following into a Terminal:

```
echo <n> | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

where `<n>` is either 0, 1 or 2 depending on the option you want to enable.

If you want to change it **permanently**, enter the following:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's#^exit 0$#echo <n> > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode\n&#g' /etc/rc.local
```

again, replacing `<n>` with 0, 1, or 2.