# Numeric keys on Apple keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard, arch-linux, numpad

I have an Apple keyboard. I have numeric keys on the {'J', 'k','l','u','i'.'o'.'p','m' } keys.

When I set Num Lock to off, it stops Num Lock for 2 seconds, and re-enables numeric keys. I tried `numlockx` and `un-apple-keyboard`, but they don't work. Is there any possibility to switch off this number key?

I already tried:

- [How to swap the "fn" use of Function keys on al Apple Keyboard in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/79822/how-to-swap-the-fn-use-of-function-keys-on-al-apple-keyboard-in-linux)
- [Apple Aluminum Keyboard and Ubunutu 11.04](https://superuser.com/questions/319751/apple-aluminum-keyboard-and-ubunutu-11-04/319763#319763)

But both don't work.

Comment: ok don't care about this, i found a solution : 
setxkbmap -option apple:badmap 
And that it's work

Comment: hmmm i try everything, and i have a moment, when i have normal keyboard, but still back this bug, I want to turn off this numeric key, i want to have normal characters :( At this moment i don't have any idea :(